# phone gap Back button alert message

Tags: android, cordova

I want to give a pop up whenever the back button is clicked. Using my code now back button is disable but it is not giving alert message.It is still not working.
My work..

```
function load()
{
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, false);
function backKeyDown() {console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");}
}

<body onLoad="load()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to Call this document addEventListener inside the pageshow function.
you have to check the backbutton event in the every page show.

This example will help you,

```
$(document).bind ('pageshow', function (e, data) {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () { 
                setTimeout( function() {console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");}, 100 );
            }, true);
        }
    });
```

Just call this bind method in the onDeviceReady method. Body onLoad Event does not work in some cases of phonegap. Use with phonegap events.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but why don't you just add a class to the button and then tell it what to do.

```
<a href="#home" class="backButton">Back</a>

$('.backButton').click(function() { alert("This should work!"); });
```