# I am trying to control the back button of a android by Phone gap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to open a pop up when I click the back button.

[This are the code which are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194935/phone-gap-back-button-alert-message)

Comment: Duplicate of [phone gap Back button alert message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194935/phone-gap-back-button-alert-message)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Check this [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) OR

Backbutton

This is an event that fires when the user presses the back button.

If you need to override the default back button behaviour you can register an event listener for the 'backbutton' event. It is no longer necessary to call any other method to over ride the back button behaviour. Now, you only need to register an event listener for 'backbutton'.

Typically, you will want to attach an event listener with document.addEventListener once you receive the Cordova 'deviceready' event.

Answer (score 0):

In you activity class add this:

@Override

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        // Do your Pop up thing here!!
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```